# Display of => and == operators in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, fonts, visual-studio-2022, ligature

In Visual Studio 2022, some operators like == and => are shown in a special way:

[image]

I'd rather turn that off but I haven't found a way to do it.

Comment: Search the settings for "ligature", as that's what those are. (Disclaimer: I have no VS 2022 installation to test with.)

Comment: Visual studio doesn't allow to turn on/off ligatures, instead you have to change font under `tools -> options -> environment -> fonts and colors`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't on by default, and ligatures are normally a property of the font you're using. Have you chosen to use a fancy "programmer" font?

Comment: @canton7, VS2022 uses Cascadia code by default: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/weve-upgraded-the-ui-in-visual-studio-2022/#more-accessibility-and-flexibility-in-editor-fonts

Comment: @JL0PD So it does, and it has ligatures enabled. What fun. OP, you can just change the font to something sensible, like the old-school Consolas

Comment: Just change font back to consolas. `Tools->Options->Fonts And Colors`. The ligatures are in the font, not as a setting

Comment: I've spent months trying to understand how to enable/disable this feature. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As people in the comments have pointed out, the only way to get rid of the ligatures is to select a font that does not have it, like Consolas.

Comment: Or, if the linked article in the comments is correct, Cascadia Mono, which is the same as Cascadia Code but without ligatures, and should also be installed by default. I personally prefer Fira Code, another font with ligatures, which has a non-ligature equivalent in Fira Mono. Of course good old Consolas remains an option as well.

Answer (score 26):

You can change from `Cascadia Code` to `Cascadia Mono`. This font doesn't support ligatures

Comment: Cascadia Mono can be found here: https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code/releases as it may not be installed along VS.

Comment: @Matthieu Cascadia Mono supported in VS

Comment: As of 17.4.5, it's not installed with VS by default, so you have to download it from the link @Matthieu referenced.

Comment: Seems to be included with VS2019, at least I never installed it myself.

Comment: I wanted to know how to _enable_ ligatures for Iosevka: https://github.com/be5invis/Iosevka